# JavaScript: Is window.spam a good practice?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've noticed all over the place people mention "**Just define a variable in the top of your JS code and it becomes global**" in response to questions like, "**How do I create a global variable from inside a function?**". Most of the answers start by saying it isn't possible to achieve that. Of course it is possible to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.spam = 'Hello World';
</script>
```

Then, later in your code, you can say:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(spam);
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine in IE6+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. So why does nobody do this?

In my case I want people to access a global variable called `fooBar` from anywhere in their code and in my AJAX library, I want the variable to update behind the scenes automatically so that when they say `$.do_some_magic()` they can be sure that `fooBar` will reflect the changes made by `$.do_some_magic()` without having to think about it. I don't want them to have to create the variable up high in their code and I don't want to create the variable up high in my library code either. I suppose I just hate defining global variables at the top and would rather not unless there is a good reason not to. Is there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Clarity**

Its an explicit way of showing that you meant to create a global variable.

```
// Unclear: Intentional, or accident
function privateScope() {
  spam = "hello";

  function globalFunction() {

  }
}
```

That will make a variable global simply because it was declared that way, though it is not immediately obvious the programmer intended the variable and the function to have a global scope.

```
// Clear: Intentional global use
function privateScope() {
  window.spam = "hello";

  window.globalFunction = function () {

  }
}
```

This example is more obvious.

**Best Practice**

If you know ahead of time a variable will be used with the global scope, it should be declared at the top of your file, outside all your functions:

```
var spam;
```

If you are inside a self executing anonymous function, then explicitly use `window.spam`:

```
(function(){
    // currently private to this scope
    var spam;

    ... lots of code ...

    // Expose the variable publically
    window.spam = spam;
})();
```

**Name Collision**

*anthares [brought up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218582/javascript-is-window-spam-a-good-practice/2218601#2218601) the other side of this, which is name collision*

A number of libraries expose a single top level object. You could either construct a function to do this, or use a simple object literal as a namespace:

```
(function(){
   // Expose a single top level variable
   window.YourCompany = { };

   // Private:
   var spam = "name";

   ... other code ...


   // Make public
   window.YourCompany.spam = spam;

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you *can* say `window.spam`. But you would only *need* to if you had also defined a local variable called `spam`. Otherwise just saying `spam` automatically refers to the global variable.

It's bad practice to refer to a global variable you haven't declared with `var`, but it'll work unless you use ECMAScript Fifth Edition ‘strict mode’.

Because `var` declarations are ‘hoisted’ and processed before code, there is no reason you have to define your globals “at the top”. This is perfectly valid even in strict mode:

```
function setFooTo6() {
    fooBar= 6;
}

var fooBar;
```

although I'd hesitate to do that as it's not entirely clear.

Comment: @bobince I didn't know that either, though I agree it might not be clear.